# LinkedIn Sharing via our own app, not possible to scroll

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi, linkedin-j

So we created the app called “taggrx” that enables companies to share posts they posted on linkedin, with their employees and then the employees can share these posts through this app.

No we implemented the usual linkedin share button and when clicked on the button, we can see the content to be shared but if the content exceeds a certain length which is more then the screen of the phone can show, the user cannot scroll down to actually do the sharing. (screenshots attached).

According to the developers this issue is coming from linkedin and not from the app, also it works fine for other platforms like Facebook or XING.

Open for any suggestion and advise, thank you!

Kind regards
Ricci
[screen-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knbur.png)
[screen-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6UpB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add a scrollbar.

```
$('#Menu').css('overflow-y':'scroll');
```